# OWIN hosting ASP.NET MVC 6 (vNext)

Tags: asp.net, owin, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Are there any guides on self-hosting asp.Net MVC 6 (or vNext)? I know it is supposed to be self-hostable but I dont think it's as easy as it is with web API and just calling `WebApp.Start` and passing the Startup class, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think there's already a sample self host on the vNext pages and if I remember correctly it is dead-simple!

Comment: It is pretty new technology and there isn't much out there.  Not sure why you would -1 him for asking.

Comment: I just mentioned it - i was not -1ing him. Nice you had the matching link.

Comment: @TGlatzer do you happen to have a link to the sample, would make my day if you did?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/tree/dev/samples/SampleStartups